# Torque converter failure - Related to replacing only 2 tires?

Tags: tires, transmission, awd

I've got a 2007 Honda CRV that I wish to continue to flog for a few more years at least.  Yesterday I noticed that the 'D' light for drive on the dashboard was blinking.  It stopped once I turned the car off and on again but today it started blinking again as I was driving.  From what I see online, it seems that this is an indicator that there is an issue with the transmission.

A few weeks ago I had two tires that were punctured and needed to be replaced.  I had been told in the past that in an AWD vehicle that you needed to replace all the tires at once because it can cause issues with the transmission otherwise.  The mechanic in this case said he didn't think that was true and that people said that because they wanted to sell more tires and that he would put the 2 old tires in the back and the new ones in the front.

I understand why having different radius tires can cause issues with the differential but for the CRV I understand that AWD only kicks in when they are needed.  Would having the back wheels spinning more quickly than the front cause this to happen?  I think there is a light that comes on when the AWD kicks in and I am not seeing that.

I found a forum thread [here](https://honda-tech.com/forums/honda-element-cr-v-156/tread-depth-cr-v-awd-3269133/) where a person claims that the CRV requires "3% difference, fronts rotating faster than the rear, before engaging the rear differential".  And that you'd need to have a 0.4 inches of wear difference. There are no sources for this 3% figure and I'm not sure where I could verify that or find authoritative information.

UPDATE: The code was for a pressure switch.  The transmission shop says there's a quarter-inch difference in circumference between the front and back tires.

According to the shop the torque converter was shot and needed to be replaced.  I've now done that at great expense.  The owner of the shop (who doesn't sell tires) says I should get a matching set.  I'm still unsure whether this matters.  Could issues with the torque converter be related to the rear differential?  I have a basic understanding of this and I'm not seeing how it would but I'm really biased towards not going through this again any time soon.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 Thanks but unfortunately aside from your welcome it's been the same crap experience as joining most SE sites so far.

Comment: @JimmyJames, you are welcome to discuss that point in our chat: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/340/the-pitstop. We are always looking for constructive criticism.

Comment: The flashing D is an indication of a problem with the transmission but it could be electronic rather than mechanical (there are quite a lot of possible reasons, actually). I'd recommend checking for codes via the OBD port (code readers are cheap these days and handy to have around).

Comment: @BobCross Yeah, I'm going to take it back to the guy who changed the tires and said it wasn't a problem.  He said that he's never had anyone come back with a transmission issue after doing this and that might very well be what I am going to do.  I'm also trying to figure out if it's worth shaving down the front tires.

Comment: I’m not sure on the 3% number but quote is correct in that the clutch in the rear differential only engages when the fronts are spinning faster than the rears.

Comment: @Ben So if the old (slightly smaller) tires are in the back, then it should not engage from normal driving because they will rotate more times per distance driven.  Is that logic sound?

Comment: What error codes are there? Note an engine control system code reader won't necessarily read the transmission / AWD system codes. Without the error codes, this is shooting in the dark and you won't get a good answer here. I wouldn't be surprised to find if there's an error code for "wheel rotation speed mismatch".

Comment: @juhist It's at the shop now and I am waiting for a diagnosis.  Whether or not this is the actual issue, the question of whether it could be the issue is still useful.  I've looked around a here and on google and the answers are diametrically opposed.  It's either a huge concern or not one at all.

Comment: Correct. Anecdotally it’s fairly rare that we replace all 4 tires on Awd and 4wd cars unless the difference in diameter is too great. Honda doesn’t publish specs AFAIK though I’m not a Honda tech and we use Mitchell or Identifix for SI. In general smaller than a 1/4” difference in diameter is acceptable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your transmission has only one output shaft. If there is a problem with the tire revolutions your differentials and transfer case will have to compensate for that.

In other words:

There is not a single chance that your different size tires damaged your torque converter.